How to forward POST requests from my main domain to my sub domain
I have purchased the domain "example.co" and hosted my frontend website on it. I am using "sub-domain.example.co" as a subdomain to host my backend application. My setup is as follows:
example.co is the frontend website and should only respond to GET requests.
sub-domain.example.co is the backend application that should handle POST requests.
I want to ensure that any POST request received by the example.co domain is forwarded to sub-domain.example.co while making sure that all GET requests are served normally by the example.co domain.
I have created a Cloudflare Worker to handle this, and here is the code for the Worker:
export default {
  async fetch(request) {
    const url = new URL(request.url);
    const { method } = request;

    if (method === "POST") {
      url.hostname = 'sub-domain.example.co';

      // Create a new request with the updated URL
      const newRequest = new Request(url.toString(), {
        method: request.method,
        headers: request.headers,
        body: request.body,
        redirect: 'manual' // Ensure we manually handle redirects
      });

      try {
        // Fetch the new request and return the response
        const response = await fetch(newRequest);
        return response;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error forwarding request:', error);
        return new Response('Error forwarding request', { status: 500 });
      }
    }

    // Allow GET requests to be handled normally
    return fetch(request);
  }
};


Verified the DNS records are proxied through Cloudflare.
Ensured the Worker script is correctly deployed and associated with the routes example.co/* and  .example.co/.


Your code seems fine to me. Are you having a specific problem with it? Your question doesn't state what's wrong.
Note that you can replace this:
      const newRequest = new Request(url.toString(), {
        method: request.method,
        headers: request.headers,
        body: request.body,
        redirect: 'manual' // Ensure we manually handle redirects
      });

With this:
      const newRequest = new Request(url.toString(), request);

The redirect property is always set to "manual" for incoming requests already, so this should produce the same results.
But I think the code should work fine either way.
